# Detect on which (of two) tableview a doubleclick happened

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have two tableviews (one for employees and one for projects) and want to check on which a doubleclick happened. After that the data of the selected Item in the selected TableView should be loaded into TextFields.

My Employees just have an ID, a surename and a forename.
In Projects there is an ID and a projectname

```
@FXML
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) //Checking double click
    {
        if(event.getTarget() == mitarbeiterview) {
            Mitarbeiter abk = mitarbeiterview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            eintragVorname.setText(abk.getVorname());
            eintragNachname.setText(abk.getNachname());
        }else if(event.getTarget() == projektview) {
            Projekt abk = projektview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            eintragBezeichnung.setText(abk.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the event handler is added to the `TableView`, then check the event _source_ instead of the event _target_. Another option is to use two event handlers, one per table.

Comment: I added onMouseClicked="#projectviewClicked" in the fxml and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend listening to the `selectedItem` property instead, since this also covers selection changes caused by pressing the arrow keys or programmatically changing the selection.